# Mysqli IN get results with duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,1,3,4,5,2);
```

I need to return result with duplicates.

Here my results need to return where id = 1 or id = 2 rows twice, others ones.

Comment: use group by having count(*) > 1 to return only duplicated rows

Comment: doesn't seems to work) returns mysqli error

Comment: SELECT p.rel, p.img, p.tech_text, p.price, p.dis_price, pl.url, pl.title FROM v_products p 
       JOIN v_products_langs pl ON p.rel = pl.pRel 
       WHERE p.rel IN ({$productsRel}) AND pl.langCode = '{$lang}' GROUP BY having count(*) > 1

Comment: there's more to it... GROUP BY fields.....

Comment: my mistake, sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL`, with a separate query for each `id` that you want duplicated.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` IN (1, 2)
```

Another way is with a join with a synthesized table that contains duplicates:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` AS t1
JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 4
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 5
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Another way would be to duplicate rows in PHP when processing the results. So you could have an array like this:

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2);
$id_counts = array_count_values($ids);
$all_results = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $all_results = array_merge($all_results, array_fill(0, $id_counts[$row['id']], $row));
}
```

Comment: Only one thing. id = 1 in my string may repeat 1000 times ))

Comment: That's too bad. You have to repeat them as many times as necessary.

Comment: It's not possible to do it in a single `WHERE` clause. That just tests whether a row matches, and either includes it in the result or doesn't. It can't duplicate rows.

Comment: what about to get results in loop?

Comment: I've add a method that duplicates the rows in PHP when processing the results.

Comment: I replaced the loop with `array_fill()`, that should be fast.